# Apple Test-Flight test in a payment application

Tags: ios, app-store, payment, testflight

I am developing a payment application for apple users, where users will have an account and will be able to recharge using apple pay.

Its fine while my application is in production. Below **Figure 8-1 Production**.

But while my application is in testflight of apple. A listed users(allowed by me) can download/update his/her testflight application from store, Also can recharge his account balance using sandbox of apple pay.

According to guideline of Apple store.
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/AppReview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH10-SW1

[image]

As the **Figure 8-1(App review)** of the above link though the users pay from his/her sandbox apple pay account user will receive money in his production account!!!

My question is

**What is the better way to handle those transactions of apple sandbox transactions?**

and

**How typical payment applications handle those types of situations?**

Answer (score 2):

You have to understand the difference between Testflight users and sandbox users for testing in-app purchases.

You are sending your test users to test the app via Testflight and you invite them with their real email address.

They can never do a sandbox purchase with their real (production) account that they currently use in the App Store for example.

Here is what you have to do:

1. Go to iTunes Connect - https://itunesconnect.apple.com
2. Go to Users and Roles
3. In the top right select Sandbox Testers
4. Add a test user (first & last name, email address (not the email that someone uses for the App Store - I like to use a fake email like test@testApp.com or whatever)

Now you can share this email address with your tester(s), then they have to go to App Store or Settings - iTunes & App Store and log out of their account and log in with your sandbox account (they will be switched to the App Store that you specified for the sand box user so you can see how it would work for someone in USA vs. someone in Italy or China).

As you can see in the image below all Sandbox payments will have [Environment: Sandbox] written on them. And no money will be exchanged since you are only testing to see if your in-app purchases or subscriptions work...hope it helps

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
In your image

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
But its not ok for me.
Yes I know no money will be exchanged. For the transaction shown in your image no money will be exchanged but for this user will receive 100 coin in his account. Otherwise user will not be able to test the application completely. isn't it?

My question is how to handle the 100 given coins. So that user will not be able to use the coin in production(real products).

Comment: This is up to you how you handle this. Maybe in the app you can store that these coins were purchashed using Sandbox and then they will not count after a while. Apples sandboxing is there only so that you can test the app and how the in-app purchases work so that when real users come and pay for your purchases your app/game works as expected.

Comment: Yes, its upto me. I think in some way. But I wanted to know a better way. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think Apple has given recommended approach in your mentioned article.

> When validating receipts on your server, your server needs to be able to handle a production-signed app getting its receipts from Apple’s test environment. The recommended approach is for your production server to always validate receipts against the production App Store first. If validation fails with the error code “Sandbox receipt used in production”, validate against the test environment instead.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
In my case I do the recommended approach. But I give coin to the users in production though paid in sandbox of apple. Otherwise the tester will not be able to test completely. 

Actually I need a better way to handle those transactions.